# .NET Build JSON Schema for a provided JSON string

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I am trying to build a JSON schema starting from a JSON string but i can't find any useful method in Json.NET. I have the follwing Json string:

```
[
    [
        [
            false,
            true,
            false
        ],
        [
            true,
            false,
            true
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            false,
            true,
            false
        ],
        [
            true,
            false,
            true
        ]
    ]
]
```

and i want parse this string in order to obtain the following schema

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": { "type": "boolean" }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that JSchema.Parse() method can accept as parameter only a string representing a schema but it's not what i want. I Want extract the schema of a specific JSON document so i can validate it in the future.

I tried combining JsonSchema4 library with Newtonsoft JSchema as the following but without good results:

```
//arrStr contains the JSON document. 
var schema = JSchema.Parse(JsonSchema4.FromSampleJson(arrStr).ToString());
```

I have no other idea to accomplish this task.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik What will it do?

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik i need a way to accomplish this in C# code not using an external tool. Anyway json2csharp generate a class. I need the schema for that JSON!

Comment: @Andorath I have used this site (https://jsonschema.net/) before to generate a schema for my JSON validation: https://jsonschema.net/ Do you want an answer on how to validate as well?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani no at the moment i just want to obtain the schema of a provided json string. Something like this https://www.jsonschema.net/ but of course coding in C#.

Comment: with the tools above , please use the documentation https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GeneratingSchemas.htm

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik the problem is that i don't know a priori what Type i hace to serialize. My program receives json document and from this json it must extract a schema. I can't use JSchemaGenerator because i have no Class associated to the incoming JSON. It's just a string coming from the outside and its structure is unknown. I hope i was clear, sorry for  my english.

Comment: i gave you a website that creates a class from a json string

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik the JSON structure is always different! It's not the same. If it was the same the solution was trivial :D

Answer (score 0):

please look at a separate library https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema

Comment: I don't have the schema string but just the JSON value! I have to parse the JSON value in order to obtain the corresponfing schema.

Comment: just put whatever you have in the string above tell me what happens

Comment: JsonSchema4 doesn't have a metod called FromJson and it isn't in the package Newtonsoft.Json.Schema. It's in NJsonSchema package.

Comment: so many versions its a pain to know which one you have, i edited above

Comment: please look at a separate library https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema

Comment: Already done. I found nothing to generate the schema associated to a json string. It always require a type to parse or, at most, a json string representing a schema. Not what i need.